# Lifting regular morphisms to the finite cover.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^d \rightarrow \text{Sym}^m(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)$ be a regular morphism. Assume $d\geq 2$ and $m, n$ are arbitrarily large compared to $d$. Then is it necessarily possible to lift this map to $(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)^{\times m}$? (Note there is a natural map from $(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)^{\times m}$)

Very rough and intuitive idea that suggests why something like this might be possible:

1. First of all if $m$ and $n$ are very large the singular locus of  $\text{Sym}^m(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)$ is going to have a very large codimension. If a map from  $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^d$ completely lands in the smooth part then it is liftable. It basically follows from the fact that the projective space is simply connected. More precisely you will need to look at the graph of the morphism and take its inverse image in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^d \times(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)^{\times m} $, because $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^d$ does not have any not trivial finite etale cover it will follow that the inverse image consists of varieties which admits an isomorphism to $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^d$ by a projection map which means it is liftable.
2. Without going into details I will claim that a similar argument implies that if a codimension $\geq 2$ part of $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^d$ gets into the singular locus of $\text{Sym}^m(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)$ it will be liftable. This can be shown by a similar argument and using Nagata-Zariski theorem (at some point taking normalization of the covers will be required).
3. It also seems that the limit of liftable maps is also liftable. (This is true in the algebraic geometric sense when the varieties are projective and my argument involves using the topology on the Chow varieties.)
4. If the singular locus of $\text{Sym}^m(\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n)$ has a high codimension then intuitively it seem that a generic map is going to lie in the smooth part and it might be possible to write every other map as the limit of liftable maps and thus all maps might be liftable.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this is possible?

Comment: @Sasha I added some intuitive arguments that why this might be possible. My arguments do not illuminate why I have assumed $d\geq 2$, I am not quite sure about that assumption so if you have a counter-example for the curve case that is also interesting to see.